# Zend Form file input set required false is not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm having the following code to render a zend form file input

```
$pd_photo = new Zend_Form_Element_File('photo');
$pd_photo->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../uploads');
$pd_photo->setRequired(false);
$pd_photo->setAllowEmpty(true);
$pd_photo->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
$pd_photo->addValidator('Size', false, 2097156672);
$pd_photo->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp');

$pd_photo->getValidator('Count')
         ->setMessage('You can upload only one file');
$pd_photo->getValidator('Size')
         ->setMessage('Your file size cannot upload file size limit of 1 MB');
$pd_photo->getValidator('Extension')
         ->setMessage('Invalid file extension, only valid image extensions are 
                      (jpg, jpeg, png, gif, bmp) allowed.');
```

All is working fine but when I leave the file filed empty then, it does not work. The zend form validator returns an empty error string message.

What wrong am doing??

Comment: You form should normally work fine. Can you please show us how you validate your form? Also, providing the HTML code generated by your form will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer, this might be right because,
I also once had the similar problem, I saw that you have used both

```
$pd_photo->setRequired(false);
$pd_photo->setAllowEmpty(true);
```

In this case you should also define for `'NotEmpty' => 'false'`

Try defining the above property for file element this should solve your problem, mine was resolved by this.